# connection to sql server(default instance) "." vs "(local)"

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server is installed in the default instance.if I want to connect to the local machine(default instance) I use "." or 
"(local)".if any difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

`.`, `(local)` and `localhost` are all aliases for the default instance on the local server, with no difference between them. If the local memory transport is enabled, that will be used. Note that this is quite different from using `::1` or `127.0.0.1`, as that forces a TCP/IP connection (as does `tcp:.` if you really wanted to force the issue).